# In the quarkus extension How do I register @RegisterRestClient's class to CombinedIndexBuildItem

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client, quarkus-extension

I'm writing a quarkus extension.
My extension runtime depends     'quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson'
deployment depends  'quarkus-rest-client-reactive-jackson-deployment'.

I want to build a restClient into my extension.

This is my class:

```
@RegisterRestClient
public interface QuarkusExchangeRestClient {

    @GET
    @Path("/url")
    String findByIds(@QueryParam("ids") String ids, @QueryParam("fetcher") String fetcher);
}
```

When I register my class in BuildStep

```
@BuildStep
    void registerBeanProducers(CombinedIndexBuildItem combinedIndex,
            BuildProducer<AdditionalBeanBuildItem> additionalBeans) {
            AdditionalBeanBuildItem.Builder builder = AdditionalBeanBuildItem.builder().setUnremovable();
            builder.addBeanClass(QuarkusExchangeRestClient.class);
            additionalBeans.produce(builder.build());
        
    }
```

When I debug

In RestClientReactiveProcessor method without parsing to  @RegisterRestClient QuarkusExchangeRestClient classes

beans.xml seems to solve my problem, but I don't want some classes in my extension to be automatically scanned in

I was wondering if there was any other way around this

Is there some buildItem that can help me solve this problem Or is there any documentation that can help me solve this problem

Can you tell me if you can why I'm not being scanned when I use AdditionalBeanBuildItem

Thank you for seeing here

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make this work is to make Quarkus aware of the code in the `runtime` part of your extension - and the easiest way to do that as you saw is via `beans.xml`.

Comment: I find the AdditionalIndexedClassesBuildItem through code can solve my problem, thank you for your answer  @geoand